# How to prevent myself from accidentaly opening android ads?

Tags: ads

So, quite often i miss the little "X" in the corner of my phone screen when trying to close an ad. It then opens in quick succession my default browser and then the play store. This process is enough to make my phone reach the end of its performance, meaning that any taps on the "Back"-Button etc. cause a few seconds of lag, causing major annoyance on my side.

Searching for solutions only yielded articles describing measures by Google reducing the likeliness of these accidental clicks by ignoring very early clicks after the ad loads etc..

But i noticed that quite often the browser opens a link starting with some kind of "ad-relay"-sounding url-names ("ad4m.at", "ad4mat.de", "ad4.adfarm1"...) and i was wondering if i could at least make my browser ask for my confirmation before sending me to the follow-up page. I am using Chrome and could not find anything like that in the settings, but i would be willing to change browsers if another one supports this feature but Chrome does not.

I would also be happy about alternative solutions to my problem, if there are any.

Comment: 1. Block ads system-wide. 2. Avoid Google products as much as possible.

Comment: You can install a system wide ad blocker like [Blockada](https://blokada.org/index.html).

Comment: Actually, i don't want to block them out completely, as i am ok with watching them to support the developers of certain apps i am using. I just don't want them to cost me as much time when i accidentally hit them again.

Comment: Try clearing defaults for your Chrome / default browser and then see if you get asked by the OS to load the ad-link in a compatible app, such as Chrome browser. If yes, you can try living with keeping your Chrome and other browser apps not set as default browser. Thereon, your OS would show you that "open with" bottom sheet every time you would click a hyperlink in an app which requires a separate browser to load it.

Comment: @WhiteMaple if you want to support developers (which we should), pay/donate them, preferably not through Play Store. Ads benefit Google more than developers. Giving a large share in everything to wealth giants like Google and Facebook, just because they are giving us some good products and platforms, doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically use the back button. Since it's not on the screen (Samsung J3V) I don't run the risk of accidentally tapping on the ad. But there are times when the back button doesn't work, which is frustrating, and you just have to use the small X.

Comment: Good idea! Although my phone does not have a separate back button, it often shows the on-screen back button automatically during ads.

Comment: I tried it for a while and it works very well. Even if the on-screen back button does not show you can use navigation gestures like swipes on the edge of your screen to perform the "back"-command. Haven't had a single accidental ad click since.

Comment: That's great to hear!